# C# Using If Statements with enum

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, enums, code-first

I want a different viewbag message displayed depending on which option is chosen from a dropdownlist of Enumerators however I'm not sure how to do this. Im using a viewmodel and passing the data through the controller, here is the ViewModel and class, an explanation on how to use if statements with ViewModels/Enumerators would be highly beneficial. I have tried assigning variables but Im realizing that all im doing is saying THIS is THIS, so thats not going to get the data from the Orders Postage enum. Any help and explanations appreciated, still learning.

ViewModel;

```
{
    public class MyOrdersViewModel
    {
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public decimal Total { get; set; }
        public bool HasBeenShipped { get; set; }
        public Postage? PostageList { get; set; }
        public List<MyOrderDetails> Details { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyOrderDetails
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Colour { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller;

```
        public ActionResult Index(Order order)
        {
            string currentUser = this.User.Identity.GetUserName();

            List<T_shirt_Company_v3.ViewModels.MyOrdersViewModel> list = (from o in new TshirtStoreDB().Orders
                    .Where(o => o.Username == currentUser)
                    .OrderByDescending(o => o.OrderDate)
                    .Select(o => new MyOrdersViewModel()
                    {
                        OrderId = o.OrderId,
                        Address = o.Address,
                        FirstName = o.FirstName,
                        LastName = o.LastName,
                        City = o.City,
                        OrderDate = o.OrderDate,
                        PostalCode = o.PostalCode,
                        Total = o.Total,
                        HasBeenShipped = o.HasBeenShipped,
                        PostageList = o.PostageList,
                        Details = (from d in o.OrderDetails
                                   select new MyOrderDetails
                                   {
                                       Colour = d.Product.Colour,
                                       Quantity = d.Quantity,
                                       Title = d.Product.Title,
                                       UnitPrice = d.UnitPrice
                                   }).ToList()
                    }).ToList()
                                                                          select o).ToList();

            //@ViewBag.PostageStatus
            //ViewBag.ShippedMessage = list.Where(w => w.HasBeenShipped).Any() ? "Order has been shipped" : "Order is being processed";

            Postage value = Postage.FirstClass;
            Postage value2 = Postage.StandardDelivery;
            Postage value3 = Postage.TwentyFourHour;

            if (value == Postage.FirstClass)
            {
                ViewBag.PostageStatus = ("First Class");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.PostageStatus = (" Error ");
            }
            if (value2 == Postage.StandardDelivery)
            {
                ViewBag.PostageStatus = ("Standard Delivery");
            }
            if (value3 == Postage.StandardDelivery)
            {
                ViewBag.PostageStatus = ("24 hour delivery");
            }

return View(list);
        }
```

Order Class

```
namespace T_shirt_Company_v3.Models
{
    //[Bind(Exclude = "OrderId")]
    public partial class Order
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int OrderId { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public System.DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        [Remote("CheckUserName", "Account")]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(16, ErrorMessage = "Your name is too long")]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Your last name is required.")]
        [StringLength(16, ErrorMessage = "Last name is too long.")]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is required.")]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "City is required.")]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Postcode is required.")]
        [Display(Name = "Post Code")]
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Country is required.")]
        public string Country { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone number is required.")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}", ErrorMessage = "Email doesn't look like a valid email address.")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("Email")]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm your email address")]
        public string EmailConfirm { get; set; }


        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public string PaymentTransactionId { get; set; }


        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public bool HasBeenShipped { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        //[ReadOnly(true)]
        public decimal Total { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Range(0, 2, ErrorMessage = "Select a delivery method")]
        public Postage? PostageList { get; set; }

        public CardDetails cardDetails { get; set; }
        //public List<CardDetails> cardDetails { get; set; }
        public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    }

    public enum Postage {[Display(Name = "Standard Delivery - Free")]StandardDelivery, [Display(Name = "First Class Delivery - £4.99")]FirstClass, [Display(Name = "24 Hour Delivery - £9.99")]TwentyFourHour }
}
```

Comment: Not clear what your trying to do. You populating a property named `PostageList` which I assume is your enum? In which case that's the value you should be testing. But you could just use a `DisplayAttribute` on your enum values and output that in the view rather than using `ViewBag`. All your current code does is to always set the value of `ViewBag.PostageStatus` to `"24 hour delivery"`

Comment: I've edited my question to include my Order class which shows the enumeration. The user selects which option they want, then that is what i need with the IF statements, to increase the total and Display the Viewbag @StephenMuecke

Comment: As @stephenMuecke said, there is a problem in your flow. `value`, `value2` and `value3` are always the same, so your viewbag always endsup with `24 hour delivery`

Comment: Yes, I understand that, how do i go about getting the Enumerator chosen instead of hard coding the viewbag to 24 hours @TimBourguignon

Comment: @AndreQueen, Your `if` code would need to be `if (listPostageList . == Postage.FirstClass) { .... } else if (listPostageList . == Postage.StandardDelivery { ... } else { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use a `switch` statement on the `enum`? Perhaps the misunderstanding was that the type was nullable.  With nullables you can invoke `.GetValueOrDefault` and then `switch` on the return for the `enum` value.

```
switch (order.Postage.GetValueOrDefault())
{
    case Postage.StandardDelivery:
        ViewBag.PostageStatus = "Standard Delivery";
        break;

    case Postage.FirstClass:
        ViewBag.PostageStatus = "First Class";
        break;

    case Postage.TwentyFourHour:
        ViewBag.PostageStatus = "24 hour delivery";
        break;

    default:
        ViewBag.PostageStatus = "Error";
        break;
}
```

This prevents the usage of the `if` statement and simplifies the readability for the user.

Comment: I get an error on the values, StandardDelivery etc, saying the name "" does not exist in the current context @DavidPine

Comment: I updated my answer, it needs the `Postage.` in front of the enum values.

Comment: Just made the same edits to my own, Is it better to use a switch statement on an enumerator @DavidPine

Comment: Not `enumerator`, `enumeration` -- there is a difference.

Comment: Yes, sorry, the enumeration, not on the actual enumerator haha

Comment: all of viewbags are returning StandardDelivery, checked the db and each order should be displaying a different delivery, any idea whats causing that @DavidPine ?

Comment: Yes, the `Postage` value is coming back as null. Therefor it's falling into the `Postage.StandardDelivery` -- set a breakpoint on the order as it comes back into the controller and you'll see.

Comment: Of course, Ill need to take the value from my database, not the order model!

Comment: I tried using 
switch (TshirtStoreDB.Orders.PostageList.GetValueOrDefault())
 But it still gives me errors, how can I compare the Orders.PostageList from the database not the model? @DavidPine

Comment: The issue is that you have a list, meaning there are multiples. If you have multiple orders you should have multiple values to display postage for.

Comment: How would I do that @DavidPine ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109538/discussion-between-david-pine-and-andre-queen).